# Having trouble in understanding and debugging vb.net codes

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am having trouble in understanding and debugging my vb.net set of codes.

I don't understand this code:

```
If Radio.PComm.GetInfomation = Quote.SUCCEED Then
   If Radio.PComm.Mode = CommMode.Active Then
       Radio.PComm.Mode = CommMode.Passive
       IsStart = True
   Else
       If IsStart Then
          IsStart = False
       Else
          Radio.PComm.Mode = CommMode.Passive
          IsStart = True
       End If
   End If
   t.Enabled = True
End If
```

Help me please, thank you.

Comment: If you don't know what the code does, why do you have it in the first place?  What's the context here?

Answer (score 0):

What part don't you understand? There's an if else

```
If IsStart Then
   IsStart = False
Else
   Radio.PComm.Mode = CommMode.Passive
   IsStart = True
End If
```

in an if else

```
If Radio.PComm.Mode = CommMode.Active Then
    Radio.PComm.Mode = CommMode.Passive
    IsStart = True
Else
    'First bit
End If
t.Enabled = True
```

in an If

```
If Radio.PComm.GetInfomation = Quote.SUCCEED Then
    'Second bit
End If
```